# User with multiple roles, access always denied

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Users may have multiple roles, e.g. `ROLE_USER, ROLE_SUBSCRIBTION_FOO, ROLE_SUBSCRIBTION_BAR`.

Based on their role I define an access control list:

```
    - { path: ^/admin/helpdesk/foo, roles: ROLE_SUBSCRIPTION_FOO }
    - { path: ^/admin/helpdesk/index, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The role hierarchy

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUBSCRIBTION_FOO: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

The problem now is, when user has the role `ROLE_SUBSCRIBTION_FOO` and accesses  `/admin/helpdesk/foo` access is denied. The user has both ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SUBSCRIBTION_FOO. However when I have

```
- { path: ^/admin/helpdesk/foo, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

it works but I need it to be

```
- { path: ^/admin/helpdesk/foo, roles: ROLE_SUBSCRIPTION_FOO }
```

which does not work, howeve the user does have the role? This is kinda weired. Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure the user you are testing has the `ROLE_ADMIN` and not `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`? Because with your actual setup a user with `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` does not have `ROLE_SUBSCRIBTION`.

Comment: Nope, user with roles a:2:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";i:1;s:21:"ROLE_SUBSCRIBTION_FOO";} is the user I am testing

Comment: Well, it seems right... Have you checked if the user has these roles in the session as well? not in the db only?

Comment: Checked array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN" [1]=> string(21) "ROLE_SUBSCRIBTION_FOO" [3]=> string(9) "ROLE_USER" }

Comment: Awww it works now. I deleted dev cache and it seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the setup everything seems right.

I want to change user roles dynamically from admin area of my application. So e.g. I give the FOO role to user BOB and expect the changes to take effect immediately.

But this does not work. The currently open session of user BOB is not refreshed. He has to reauthenticate himself. After reauthentication (logout and login again) symfonys security system will compare the role correctly with the given access list.

So I expected the user session to be updated automatically, but this is not possible with the default security system of symfony. I think it needs to be extended with database based session management. This way you could refresh the user session.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a typo to me. You defined `ROLE_SUBSCRIBTION_FOO` in your hierarchy (with a B) but you're wanting to restrict the path with `ROLE_SUBSCRIPTION_FOO` (with a P).